# Apache Airflow on Composer 2.0 Task Failed with "Not yet started" issue

Tags: airflow, scheduled-tasks

My dags consists of too many tasks around more than 600 and while running the dag at times it behaves differently i.e sometimes a task gets failed and status comes as 'Not yet started'.
Please help how to resolve this error,

Information :
Composer 2.0.10
Airflow 2.2.3
Executor : Celery
Workers : 2 to 6 Auto scale
Schedulers : 2

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.